# CKeditor Enabling Html Live Code edit

Tags: ckeditor

How to enable **Live HTML Code Edit** in CKEditor. I have tried doing this and searched the documentation, but was unable to find it. Is there any possible way to do it in CK editor.

Comment: can u explain more as to what u mean by LIVE HTML code editing?
editing the html in the editor area directly??

Comment: Yes exactly, edit HTML code in the editor

Answer (score 0):

i guess u can make a plugin which would use the getData method of CKEditor to give u the html data,
 Display it in a textarea or something,
then u could edit it and then use setData to set it back to the editor.